# Impact of Mongo API projecion in Cosmos Request unit charge

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I can read from Microsoft documentation the RU is impacted due to document size as per the documentation. Is it the size of stored document or the retrieved document. I have a document with lot of entries under the nested level. If I retrieve only the property at level 1 will it reduce the RU?

For example the document is show below. Consider the association level has more than 15000 entries

```
{
"name": "hi",
"data":"demo",
"associations": [
{
"name": "assoc1"
},
{
"name": "assoc2"
},
{
"name": "assoc3"
},
{
"name": "assoc4"
},
{
"name": "assoc5"
}
]
}
```

Wil there a difference in RU between the two mongo queries considering the document size is 500KB?

```
Query without projection:

db.getCollection("demo").find({"name":"hi"})

Query with projection:
db.getCollection("demo").find( {"name":"hi"} , {"data":true} )
```

I noticed a change in RU between this two query. But I didn't see this mentioned in the document I searched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the query engine needs to traverse a large document to project results then it will consume more RU/s than when it doesn't.

The bigger issue I think is a document with an array of more than 15K items. Unbounded or super large arrays is generally not a good pattern for Cosmos DB, especially if they have asymmetric update patterns because updates will replace the entire document.

Comment: In my scenario, the document is immutable. It won't be updated after persisting once.  Will it cause any problems in that case for 500KB document? On an average the large array can have 1000 items, but sometimes it can have 15000 items.

Comment: Not really a problem if it's immutable. But still generally smaller documents are more efficient overall than larger ones.

Comment: Got a reply from MSFT 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/600260/request-unit-charge-impact-on-mongo-db-projection.html?childToView=604153#answer-604153